pyqt5 get signal in basehttprequesthandler
I am using pyqt5 in a python3.9 environment and there is one simple but difficult problem for me.
The main purpose is to run an http server using threads in pyqt5 and send a specific API request to that server. Using the BaseHttpRequestHandler class, we set it to throw a callback value only to APIs coming to a specific address.
What I'm curious about here is, is it possible to use the value generated from BaseHttpRequestHandler inside MainWindow using pyqtSignal?
import sys
import db
import json
import requests

from datetime import datetime

from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView, QTableWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot, QThread, QTimer, pyqtSignal, QObject

from login_ui import Ui_Form
from sidebar_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

_URL = "*"
_UpdateScreen_URL = "*"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
port = *

user = None
screen_data = []
callback_data = []

class ApiServer(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def run(self):
        http_server = HTTPServer(('', int(port)), ResponseHandlerAdapter)
        http_server.serve_forever()
    
class ResponseHandlerAdapter(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        global screen_data, callback_data
        content = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['content-length']))
        resource = content.decode('utf8')
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        if self.path == '/led':
            pass
        elif self.path == '/screen':
            print("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ /SCREEN Response Data ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓")
            screen_data.append(json.loads(resource))
            print(screen_data)
        elif self.path == '/input':
            print("↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ /INPUT CallBack Data ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓")
            callback_data.append(json.loads(resource))
            print(callback_data)
        

class LoginScreen(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__()
        self.setupLoginUi(self)
        self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.login_function)
   
    def login_function(self):
        global user
        user = self.input_id.text()
        password = self.input_password.text()
        if len(user) == 0 or len(password) == 0:
            print("아이디와 패스워드를 입력해주세요.")
        else:
            check_point = db.login(user, password)
            if check_point == password:
                print(f"[로그인 성공] [{user}]")
                self.hide()
                self.main = MainWindow()
                self.main.show()
                # time.sleep(5)
                # server = ApiServer(self)
                # server.start()
                
                # print("version V1.2 %s %d" %('port:', port))
                # start_server_check_tags = []
                # for t in Tags:
                #     start_server_check_tags.append({"mac": t["mac"], "mappingtype": 574, "styleid": 48, "ledrgb": "ff0000", "ledstate": "0", "outtime": "3", "EA": "서버ON", "text_company": "copyright(C) by sd-da, All right Reserved."})
                # requests.post(url=_URL_updateScreen, headers=headers, json= start_server_check_tags)
            else:
                print("아이디와 패스워드를 확인해주세요.")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.server = ApiServer(self)
        self.server.start()

        self.ui.icon_only_widget.hide()
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.ui.home_btn_2.setChecked(True)

        # 대시보드 메뉴 관련
        self.ui.waybill_input.returnPressed.connect(self.select_data_from_waybill)
        self.ui.waybill_input.returnPressed.connect(self.send_data_to_tags)
        
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.defaultBrush = (item.foreground(), item.background())
        self.ui.db_table.itemChanged.connect(self.item_changed)

        self.set_table()

        self.ui.complete_btn_1.clicked.connect(self.set_clear)
    
    def handle_response(self, data):
        print(data)

    def set_clear(self):
        global user
        waybill_no = self.ui.waybill_input.text()
        self.ui.db_table.clear()
        self.ui.db_table.setRowCount(0)
        self.set_table()
        self.ui.waybill_input.clear()
        self.ui.waybill_input.setFocus()
        now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(now)
        # db.update_picking_finish_time(user, now, waybill_no)
        print(user)
        
    ## 테이블에서 체크박스 선택 시 row색상 변경
    def item_changed(self, item):
        if bool(item.checkState()):
            fg = QColor('#004000')
            bg = QColor('#C6EFCE')
        else:
            fg, bg = self.defaultBrush
        row = item.row()
        self.ui.db_table.itemChanged.disconnect()  
        for col in range(self.ui.db_table.columnCount()):
            item = self.ui.db_table.item(row, col)
            if item:
                item.setForeground(fg)
                item.setBackground(bg)
        self.ui.db_table.itemChanged.connect(self.item_changed)

    ## Function for searching
    def on_search_btn_clicked(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(5)
        search_text = self.ui.search_input.text().strip()
        if search_text:
            self.ui.label_9.setText(search_text)
    
    ## Function for changing page to user page
    def on_user_btn_clicked(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(6)
    
    ## Change QPushButton Checkable status when stackWidget index changed
    def on_stackedWidget_currentChanged(self, index):
        btn_list = self.ui.icon_only_widget.findChildren(QPushButton) + self.ui.full_menu_widget.findChildren(QPushButton)
        for btn in btn_list:
            if index in [5, 6]:
                btn.setAutoExclusive(False)
                btn.setChecked(False)
            else:
                btn.setAutoExclusive(True)
    
    ## functions for changing menu page
    def on_home_btn_1_toggled(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
    def on_home_btn_2_toggled(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
    def on_dashboard_btn_1_toggled(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
    def on_dashboard_btn_2_toggled(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
    def on_work_btn_1_toggled(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
    def on_work_btn_2_toggled(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
    def on_product_btn_1_toggled(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(3)
    def on_product_btn_2_toggled(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(3)
    def on_userlist_btn_1_toggled(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(4)
    def on_userlist_btn_2_toggled(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(4)

    ## QtableWeidget 설정
    def set_table(self):
        self.ui.db_table.setColumnCount(9)
        self.ui.db_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
        )

    ## 운송장 스캐닝 후 엔터키 구현
        # 682679951842
    def select_data_from_waybill(self):
        waybill_no = self.ui.waybill_input.text()
        print(waybill_no)
        rows = db.select_from_order_with_waybill(waybill_no)
        count = len(rows)
        self.ui.db_table.setRowCount(count)
        
        for x in range(count):
            for y in range(len(rows[x])):
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setText(str(rows[x][y]))
                if y == 0:
                    item.setCheckState(False)
                self.ui.db_table.setItem(x, y, item)
        
        width = []
        for column in range(self.ui.db_table.horizontalHeader().count()):
            self.ui.db_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(column, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
            width.append(self.ui.db_table.horizontalHeader().sectionSize(column))

    def send_data_to_tags(self):
        # global screen_data
        waybill_no = self.ui.waybill_input.text() 
        rows = db.select_from_mac(waybill_no)
        update_data = []
        for row in rows:
            mac = row[5]
            ea = row[3]
            update_pre_data = {"mac": mac, "mappingtype": 574, "styleid": 48, "ledrgb": "ff00", "ledstate": "0", "outtime": "0", "EA": ea, "text_company": "copyright(C) by sd-da, All right Reserved."}
            update_data.append(update_pre_data)
        response = requests.post(_UpdateScreen_URL, headers=headers, data= json.dumps(update_data))
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print('API success')
            print('응답 내용:', response.json())
        else:
            print('API failed')
            print('상태 코드:', response.status_code)
            print('응답 내용:', response.text)
        # self.waiting_interval = 3000
        # if len(screen_data) > 0:
        #     item = self.ui.db_table
        #     for row in range(item.rowCount()):
        #         item.item(row, 0).setCheckState(True)
        #         self.ui.db_table.itemChanged.connect(self.item_changed)
        #     now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        #     print(now)
        #     # db.update_picking_start_time(user, now, waybill_no)
        #     screen_data = []
    
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    login_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = LoginScreen()
    login.show()
    login_app.exec_()

Ultimately, what I want is to change the color of the row in Qtable in real time using data received from the tag device server.
screen_data like this..


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
